# Reuse Meteor template - Isolating events

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, pug

I tried:

```
  Template.skillsSearch = $.extend Template.skillsSearch,
    rendered: ->
      Session.set('s' + @_id, null)
      Session.set('searchFocused' + @_id, null)
```

`@_id` worked before, I think because it was inside an `each` statement. Now I do not have this loop and `@` is `{}`(no `_id` in the object).

Suppose I have this:

```
body
  +myTemplate
  +myTemplate
```

How could I get an unique `id` per template instance? Or, how can I make unique session keys when reusing a template?

Comment: This is a common problem, which will get a bit easier in meteor 0.8.2. I'm writing a blog post which describes a technique for solving this issue. I'll check back when it's done.

Comment: Here is my blog post on [Scoped Reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity). Hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
template(name='father1')
  with 'father1'
    +reusedTemplate

template(name='father2')
  with 'father2'
    +reusedTemplate

template(name='reusedTemplate')
  h1 #{aVariable}
```

Then in coffeescript:

```
Template.reusedTemplate = $.extend Template.reusedTemplate,
  rendered: ->
    # Here @data contains whatever you pass in with
    # i.e. 'father1' and 'father2' respectively

  aVariable: ->
    # Here @ contains whatever you pass in with
    # i.e. 'father1' and 'father2' respectively
```